# What JavaScript library should I use for creating a multimedia post with draggable elements?

Tags: javascript, web

I want to create a simple social web application, where a user can make different multimedia posts related to his favourite hobby. My user should be able to upload different videos, images, texts from local machine, and then easily drag them on top of his new post.
I need to save that post in my database, with that exact format.

What are your suggestions about this? Is there a good and intuitive JS library that is well suited for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/) in conjunction with [plupload styled as jqueryui widget](http://www.plupload.com/example_jquery_ui.php) for uploading different stuff.

jqueryui has [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/), [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) plugins which may help to implement your drag-n-drop functionality